# Angularjs transition error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am having error with my angularjs application. I used `yo angm` to generate my project. Without even editing any file, I am having an error. This means that my project is not generated correctly. This is what I get in the console:

```
angular.js:14525 Error: transition prevented
    at $StateProvider.$get (angular-ui-router.js:2904)
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:5003)
    at angular.js:4795
    at getService (angular.js:4944)
    at injectionArgs (angular.js:4969)
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:4995)
    at angular.js:8110
    at forEach (angular.js:403)
    at Object.<anonymous> (angular.js:8108)
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:5003) "Possibly unhandled rejection: {}"
(anonymous) @ angular.js:14525
angular.js:14525 Error: transition aborted
    at $StateProvider.$get (angular-ui-router.js:2905)
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:5003)
    at angular.js:4795
    at getService (angular.js:4944)
    at injectionArgs (angular.js:4969)
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:4995)
    at angular.js:8110
    at forEach (angular.js:403)
    at Object.<anonymous> (angular.js:8108)
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:5003) "Possibly unhandled rejection: {}"
(anonymous) @ angular.js:14525
angular.js:14525 Error: transition failed
    at $StateProvider.$get (angular-ui-router.js:2906)
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:5003)
    at angular.js:4795
    at getService (angular.js:4944)
    at injectionArgs (angular.js:4969)
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:4995)
    at angular.js:8110
    at forEach (angular.js:403)
    at Object.<anonymous> (angular.js:8108)
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:5003) "Possibly unhandled rejection: {}"
```

I recreate the project multiple times, but still having the same issue.

my Angular version is :  `@license AngularJS v1.6.4`

**Update**

This is my ui-router code:

```
// app.config.js

(function () {
    'use strict';

    /**
     * @ngdoc configuration file
     * @name app.config:config
     * @description
     * # Config and run block
     * Configutation of the app
     */


    angular
        .module('ang-modular')
        .config(configure)
        .run(runBlock);

    configure.$inject = ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider', '$httpProvider'];

    function configure($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider) {

        $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');

        // This is required for Browser Sync to work poperly
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';


        $urlRouterProvider
            .otherwise('/');

    }

    runBlock.$inject = ['$rootScope'];

    function runBlock($rootScope) {
        'use strict';

        console.log('AngularJS run() function...');
    }


})();

// app.js
(function() {
    'use strict';

    /**
    * @ngdoc index
    * @name app
    * @description
    * # app
    *
    * Main module of the application.
    */

    angular.module('ang-modular', [
        'ngResource',
        'ngAria',
         'ui.bootstrap',

        'ngCookies',
        'ngAnimate',
        'ngTouch',
        'ngSanitize',
        'ui.router',
        'home',
    ]);

})();
```

Can you please help me solve this ?

Thanks.

Comment: share your code regarding `ui-router`. Provide versions for that lib and if you use `ui-router-extras`, their version too

Comment: can be helpful: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/2889

Answer (score 1):

There is a small patch to get rid of these errors that is add a config as followed.

```
app.config(['$qProvider', function ($qProvider) {
    $qProvider.errorOnUnhandledRejections(false);
}]);
```

**Note**: This issue is due to Angular JS versions nothing to worry.
Reference Links: [UI-Router Github Issue Link](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/2889)